# Count repeating intervals in a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, artificial-intelligence, data-mining

[image]

In the image, you can see five repetitive peak sections. I want to write an algorithm that counts this number, but I am not sure how.

I tried to draw a regression curve using `seaborn.lmplot`, but it was drawn so flat that it didn't work. What should I do in a case like this?

Comment: Try to watch at autocorrelation signal and decide is it suitable to your needs. And please, provide data that was used for image creation.

Comment: `seaborn.lmplot` uses a linear regression fit, and this data is not linear, so one shouldn't expect that to work.